# XSLT templates with recursion and condition

Tags: xslt

I'am new to XSLT and need help

this is my XML source file:

```
<cars best-category="83">
    <category id="1" name="SUV">
        <category id = "50" name="BMW">
        </category>
    </category>
    <category id="2" name="combi">
        <category id = "60" name="Volkswagen">
           <category id="102" name="4x4">
           </category>      
        </category>                     
        <category id = "83" name="Skoda">           
        </category>
        <category id = "32" name="Seat">            
        </category>
    </category>
    <category id="12" name="another">
    </category>
</cars>
```

and I need this result (select full name attribute path by best-category value):

```
<CATEGORYTEXT>combi | Skoda</CATEGORYTEXT>
```

my XSLT:

```
       <xsl:for-each select="cars/category">              
          <CATEGORYTEXT>              
            <xsl:apply-templates select="category" >
              <xsl:with-param name="text" >
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
              </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:apply-templates>              
          </CATEGORYTEXT>
        </xsl:for-each
```

and my template:

```
<xsl:template match="category">
            <xsl:param name="text" />
            <xsl:if test="category">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="category">
                <xsl:with-param name="text">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
                  <xsl:text>&#xA;|&#xA;</xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                </xsl:with-param>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
            <xsl:text>&#xA;|&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />    
        </xsl:template>
```

bud I don't know, how filtered results by best-category value ... Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="cars">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//category[@id=current()/@best-category]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="category">
    <CATEGORYTEXT>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::category">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </CATEGORYTEXT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's ok for this exactly example, but if is there next inner category sub-element ? like this: 

`<cars best-category="87">
 <category id="2" name="combi">        
        <category id = "83" name="Skoda">           
   <category id = "87" name="4x4"></category>
        </category>
 </category>
</cars>`

or 

`<cars best-category="12">
 <category id="12" name="another">                
 </category>
</cars>`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: rule is like folder path in OS, if best-category = 12 then result is `another` only, or if 102 then `combi | Volkswagen | 4x4`